# Put a <div> element in the horizon and vertical center of the screen?

Tags: html, css, position

Here is my code:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>This sentence should be displayed in the center of the whole screen

</div>
```

I tried `margin` and `padding` to make the div in the center of the whole screen. (horizonly and vertically). However, neither `margin` nor `padding` can center the element.

Then I tried `left: 50%` and `top:50%`, it changes the position of the element, but not as expected. The left margin of `<div>` is located to `left:50%`, while I want the center of `<div>` to be located to `left:50%`..

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 3):

use - `transform: translate`

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>This sentence should be displayed in the center of the whole screen</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qa2svuLr/)**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kx4okpn/).

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.
  You need to use the transform:translate css.

```
div {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    }
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/diwask/866vnd8d/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Keep position as relative and text-align it to center, if you don't want to use translate.

```
div {
position: relative;
text-align:center;
}
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3r14kq1x/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 div {
      position: relative;
      text-align:center;
      top:50%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple and Responsive try this

```
div {
  margin: auto;
  width:50%;
}
```

[Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hop3szu4/6/)